# $_POST Form failing to create record

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm working on a simple PHP form and I'm running into a bit of a strange problem. It's occurring both on my local MAMP environment and my hosted website. The purpose of this script is to store a record into a table based on data submitted via the following form.

```
<?php
    include("dbconnect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']){
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $SQLString = "INSERT INTO name_table (first_name) VALUES($firstName)";
        mysql_query($SQLString);
    } else {
        //Debugging script
        $mypostdata = file("php://input");
        print "<pre>"; 
        var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($mypostdata);
        print "</pre>";
    }
?>

<form name="myForm" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="Bob" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Finish">
</form>
```

using var_dump on `$_POST` outputs this:

```
array(2) {
  ["firstName"]=>
  string(3) "Bob"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "Finish"
}
```

var_dump on `$mypostdata = file("php://input");` results in this:

```
array(9){
    "name=Bob&submit=Finish"
}
```

When I submit the form no record is being created in the table.

**Edit:**
For clarity I originally thought the error laid with the `$_POST['myForm']` name coming up as `NULL` but comments and answers have cleared that up.

Comment: Who said it's supposed to be posted?

Comment: Please elaborate with useful information.

Comment: I'm serious. Why are you expecting the form's name to be posted?

Comment: <form name="myForm" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">

change to

<form name="myForm" action="" method="POST">

You can leave action empty if you post too the same page / script

And never use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] again its very unsafe because of cross side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Form itself isn't listed as "Successful control" (see 17.2.1), hences its name shouldn't be submitted.

Comment: Ah thanks, I edited the post to be a bit more accurate now that I know I was wrong to assume the $_POST name would have a value other than NULL. The problem of the record not being created still persists.

Comment: php docs: `isset` — Determine if a variable is set and is not *NULL*.

Answer (score 0):

If first_name is a varchar, then it needs to be wrapped in single quotes in the MySQL query. E.g.:

```
"INSERT INTO name_table (first_name) VALUES('$firstName')";
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
    $SQLString = "INSERT INTO name_table (first_name) VALUES($firstName)"; to 
    $SQLString = "INSERT INTO name_table (first_name) VALUES(".$firstName.")";

if it not works display page errors by writing error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors",1);

Keep posting the results